# How to add multiple row in bootstrap-table footer?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-table

I need to show all the tally of specific column into my table footer.

But unfortunately I can't find any documentation regarding this matter.

Any idea how can I achieve it?

Please see images below for reference:

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8J0V.jpg)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLTQQ.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using jQuery [DataTable plugin](https://datatables.net/) . It has similar [example here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

Comment: for custom approach you can review this one [jQuery-Bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/7uekynd4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First, add this to your table,

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
       <th colspan="6" class="text-right">Total: </th>
       <th colspan="2"></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Then add the following script:

```
  $('.tableClassor#tableID').DataTable({
  dom: '<"top">rt<"bottom"lfp><"clear">',
  footerCallback: function (row, data, start, end, display) {
  var api = this.api(), data;

    //Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
    var intVal = function (i) {
      return typeof i === 'string' ?
        i.replace(/[$,]/g, '')*1 :
        typeof i === 'number' ?
        i : 0;
    };

    //Total over all pages, 
    total = api
      .column( 6 )
      .data()
      .reduce( function (a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      }, 0);

    //Total over this page
    pageTotal = api
      .column( 6, {page: 'current'})
      .data()
      .reduce(function (a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      }, 0 );

    //Update footer
    $(api.column( 6 ).footer() ).html(
       '$ '+pageTotal +' ( $ '+ total +' total )'
    );
  }
})
```

Adjust the `colspan` value to align the total with the column you want to tally.